# The element type 'Set<Widget?>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'

Tags: flutter, dart, if-statement, mobile, widget

I am using Flutter, and trying to show Image asset (question.answerImage) if it is not null.
I wrote a code as follows, but it returns an error.

```
...
content: Column(children: [
             if (question.answerImage!=null){question.answerImage},
             ...
```

Error is written as follows:

> The element type 'Set<Widget?>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'.

How can I change the type Set<Widget?> to type Widget?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are using if/else statements in Collection literals.

Remove the curly braces.

```
...
content: Column(children: [
         if (question.answerImage!=null)question.answerImage,
         ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I removed the curly braces, but the error still exists..

Comment: Thank you very much, I found it worked once I added ! at last of your code!

Answer (score 0):

If there is some widget other than 'question.answerImage',
you need to use 'spread operator' to seperate List to each Widget.
https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/dart-using-triple-dot-spread-operator-examples

```
[Example]

Column(children: [
    ...question.answerIamge,
    Container(...),
    Row(...),
  ]
)
```

```
...
content: Column(children: [
             if (question.answerImage!=null)...question.answerImage,
             ...
```

Comment: @tasmicsy I changed answer because there is no reason to change from set to list. You can do by just using 'spread' operator.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I used ... to my code, but it didn't work. However, it is nice to know spread operator because I didn't know it. Thank you!

Comment: I missed that 'Remove the curly braces' this point. But I wonder whether '[ question.answerImage]' is ok without using spread operator.